# How to find the smallest and largest freq or word in an list of objects represented by an object python

Tags: object, python-3.x

I have an object that represents a list of objects. Each of these represents a word and its frequency of occurrence in a file.
each object in the list has a word, and the frequency that it shows up in a file. Currently i'm getting an error that says "object is not iterable".

```
#each object in the list looks like this
#word = "hello", 4

def max(self):
    max_list = [None, 0]
    for item in WordList:
        if item.get_freq() > max_list[1]:
            max_list[0] = item.get_word()
            max_list[1] = item.get_freq()
    return max_list
```

how do i find the max and min frequency of these objects

Note: this is in a class WordList and that get_word and get_freq is in the class that created the objects in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not clear to me.  Using 'object' in the title is at least once too many.  The function does not use `self`.  If `WordList` is a class, you cannot iterate it.  Etc. However, I will try to give you an answer to what I think you are asking, which you might be able to adapt.

```
def minmax(items)
    """Return min and max frequency words in iterable items.

    Items represent a word and frequency accessed as indicated.
    """
    it = iter(items)
    # Initialize result variables
    try:  
        item = next(items)
        min_item = max_item = item.get_word(), item.get_freq()
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError('cannon minmax empty iterable')
    # Update result variables
    for item in it:
        word = item.get_word()
        freq = item.get_freq()
        if freq < min_item[1]:
            min_item = word, freq
        elif freq > max_item[1]:
            max_item = word, freq
    return min_item, max_item
```